# result of a loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

In my loop each row is examined and equal to "yes" or "no". When the loop is finished, I want to know if I got a "yes".

This is my code:

```
for( int i=0;i<[car count];i++) {
    NSDictionary *test = [car objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([[test objectForKey:@"car"] isEqualToString:[test2 objectForKey:@"red"]]) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
}
```

just want to know how many "yes" I had in my loop

Comment: This code is incomplete. Can you amend this because it's hard to see what you're looking for.

Comment: I just want to know how many "yes" I had in my loop

Comment: make it a function, if you get a yes return true (exiting the loop), otherwise return false after the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a an integer variable to keep track of positive matches, set it to 0 before the loop, then increment it by 1 on every positive match and after the loop check how many you got.

```
NSInteger somethingFound = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [car count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *test = [car objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([[test objectForKey:@"car"] isEqualToString:[test2 objectForKey:@"red"]]) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        somethingFound++;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
}
if (somethingFound) {
    NSLog("found %d", somethingFound);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to count how many "yes" results you captured, include an integer property in the class and increment it by 1 for every "yes" you get.

```
if ([[test objectForKey:@"car"] isEqualToString:[test2 objectForKey:@"red"]]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
    someInt++;
} else {
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

Comment: But mine was the first reply! It's ok. :P

Comment: It was a few seconds (I didn't even get the notification), so it probably rounded our "answered" to same number of minutes when OP was reading them. I agree that first answer should be accepted, but here is a +1 to make it a bit less unfair just in case ;)